# no puedo iniciar sesion en mi app desde el celular u otro dispositivo

Tags: laravel

cuando inicio sesion desde mi pc en la cual estoy desarrollando la app, puedo logearme bien, pero si intento con cualquier otro dispositivo en mi red local , no me deja logearme me sla eel error 419 page expired, lo raro es que si puedo navegar en ella. y si abro otro proyecto puedo logearme en cualquier dispositivo, en google lei que puede ser problema del form y el @csrf pero mi formulario por ahora es el que viene  por defecto, no se me ocurre que puede llegar a ser.
alguna sugerencia?

login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                            {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Login') }}
                                    </button>

                                    @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                            {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                        </a>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto funcionó

```php
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

si con solo esto no funciona en la herramienta de desarrollo de tu navegador ve a la parte de almacenamiento > cookies y elimina todas las cookies a mano.

Comment: Me pide dejar pasar 2 días, no lo olvidaré ,gracias